# Setting up an automated repeating task in SugarCRM Professional?

Tags: sugarcrm

Does anyone know how to set up an automated repeating task in SugarCRM Professional version 6.X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sugarcrm scheduler, but you would have to create the task through code. You can access schedulers from Administration page.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow module can automatic create task, not sure can you create new task when a task is closed.